# PHP correct way to exit forloop

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I have a snippet of PHP code like this:

```
  while($attempts < $cycles) {

        foreach($player_array as $player) {
                if(isset($player['results']) && $player['results'] == 1) {
                        $player['results'] = player_search($f, $s, $t);
                }
        }
}
```

The idea is for each item in the array it calls a search function. If the search has nothing, it returns false, which SHOULD stop it from calling the search for the rest of the remaining cycles by changing the value of 'results'.

I'm assuming that setting `$player['results']` as false does not actually set the correct variable for when it pulls it in on the next iteration.

How should i change my code to get this working properly?

EDIT:

Can I make clear that if a search in a function returns no results I do not want that function to be called again, I DO however want the same function to be used for the other searches if they still have results. Obviously once all player searches have no result i would ideally like to break the while loop too.

Comment: if you are in a function why don't you just return? Otherwise I think "break" exists in php

Comment: or 'if(player_search($f, $s, $t)!==false){.....}else{break;}'

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you are trying to do? I don't see the point of your while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whats going on with $attempts and $cycles since they dont seem to be changed from within the loop but if you really want to change the value in $player contained in $player_array you should do

```
foreach($player_array as &$player) {
    if(!isset($player['results'])) {
        $player['results'] = player_search($f, $s, $t);
    }
}
```

notice I changed `$player` to `&$player` so that it becomes a reference instead of a copy

I also changed your isset so that it only does a search if the results are not stored in results already

Comment: Can you explain what the &$player change means?

Comment: it makes `$player` a reference instead of a copy. So that when you edit it it sticks

Comment: If thats the case, you my friend seem to be the man who understands! So I return false in the function if there's no results, and i don't return anything if there is results? I need to repeat searches because I can only search a small number of items at a time. It is also a timely search so I don;t want the function to even call if there was no results on the previous search

Comment: the altered if statement I have in my answer should cover that case when it returns false.

Answer (score 3):

Use `break 2;` to exit both the `foreach` and the `while`

```
while($attempts < $cycles) {
    foreach($player_array as $player) {
        if(isset($player['results']) && $player['results'] == 1) {
            $player['results'] = player_search($f, $s, $t);
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Example from the PHP Manual : http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 2):

Use [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) after you found (or not?) a match.

And to stop the while loop as well: `break 2;`

If this is code is within function and you have nothing else there, you might as well return the result.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesnt set the variable is because you are only setting one $player with the results as 1 or 0 (or true/false). The next time in the loop, the $player variable is not the same as the previous. Why not do something like this?

```
while($attempts < $cycles) {
  foreach($player_array as $player) {
    if(isset($player['results']) && $player['results'] == 1) {
      if(!player_search($f, $s, $t)) break;
      else //something here
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to break out of the while loop also, you can always do `break 2;`